# How to send Raw JSON Post request c++

Tags: c++, json, rest, request

I'm working on a little project and am just wondering how I would send raw JSON as a post request? For Example.

I would like to send this below as Raw JSON to my API.

```
{
    "Username": "test",
    "Password": "test"
}
```

If that data is valid, the API response will be something along the lines of

```
{
    "State": "Success",
    "Version": 1.0,
    "Expiry":  1557872940
}
```

I am able to Process the data from the response and am only looking for an http library in which can POST RAW JSON Data.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: It is a question, I'm not asking for a recommendation.

Comment: You need some HTTP library (because you don't want to do that manually), e.g. https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib#client-example

Comment: You also need some JSON processing library, e.g. https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/ unless your JSON is a string to begin with (i.e. your app doesn't care about structure).

Comment: I'm familiar with RapidJson, just needed a library that could Post raw JSON, Thank you though :)

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. Have a look at the help page, and read about what kind of questions are suitable here.

Comment: @CharlesClide at the time I said "*Asking for recommendations is off-topic*", your post still said "*If anyone could **recommend some libraries** that work*", but that was removed from your post afterwards.

Comment: I didn't change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a HTTP library such as Chilkat. You can get it [Here](https://www.example-code.com/cpp/http_post_json.asp)